# How to change the node breadcrum name & there url inside in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, breadcrumbs

There is a node where breadcrum shows like this :

```
Home › Shop Products › Product Name
```

Now I want to change the breadcrum. I can easily change the *"Product Name"* but unable to change the *"Shop Products"* name. How can I change. I have try to add custom code in **template.php** file but unable to got result.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I would recommend trying path_breadcrumbs module

Comment: I have already use this module. Actually I am working on developed website. I am findout any text related "Shop Products".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the appearance of the breadcrumb using theme_breadcrumb function in your template.php
[Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7) is a page with several snippets of example code you can use to get some inspiration on how you should write your code.